# Is there a better way to show 3 states within a list of items

Tags: lists, column

Info:
There is space and capacity for one single column of names. The names need space to have emails input. 
[image: List]

These names can be in one of three states- invite not sent, pending, and invited. Here is an example of how it is currently planned. 
[image: List2]

You can see that the pending and connected states seem different enough to warrant something but Im not sure how to go about it without splitting it into three separate categories (invites not sent, pending, and invites sent).
In the mock below, as invites are sent they fall down into the "invites sent" category. Is there a better way to organize these items in a single column list?

Answer (score 2):

You may try this

[image]

[image]

You can change the sequence/order of your section contextually. i.e If your purpose is to send invites, Bring invite section to top.

Answer (score 0):

For one, instead of "Pending", you can make it say "Sent". That way, if it gets declined (technically not "pending" anymore) you can still show "sent" and not lie.

Secondly, I'm not sure if there's a reason to show the email address. Also, the "Invite another" button is a bit ambiguous. Does it invite someone else? Then why put it inline with each user? I'm guessing it should say "re-invite" or "re-send invitation" or something along those lines.

But to answer your question; I'm not sure the "invite sent" section is necessary. You might as well show those in between the ones that have not been sent yet, in however order you're going to put them (alphabetical?).

The main reason why you could leave them there, is that **"Invite sent" is implied by the words "pending" and "connecting"**.

If you think the list will grow too long to do this, and want a bit better organization, try thinking along the lines of filtering. Create some tabs at the top of the page that split it into a "sent" and "not sent" list, or whatever you'd name them.

Comment: If they all stay inline regardless of their state I wonder if it would be harder to organize who has or hasnt been invited yet. Much how to-do lists pull the items that require attention to the top, wouldnt it help the user to clump the items that still require action?

Comment: It could, but that depends a bunch of things. For example, if those lists are prone to growing huge, yeah, sure. My worry about separated sections came mainly from these words you used: *"they fall down"*. This might imply that they get "lost". I've added another paragraph to maybe better handle your issue.

Comment: Lets say we did use tabs- once everyone was invited there would just be an empty state. If it reverted to no tabs once everyone was invited I feel like that would be confusing "How do I know everyone is invited if I dont see the list of people that havent connected yet" sort of dilemma